# PHP strings omit text because of PHP short tags wrap it

Tags: php, string, escaping, eval

A simple code sample `<?echo '<?this text is ignored?> this text is shown';?>` writes just "this text is shown" and ignores the text inside php tags despite it's a string.

Unfortunately, I can't find any explanation in specs, so, how to handle this? I know, that we can escape special symbols and everything goes all right, but what's the matter of such php behaviour?

PHP 5.3, local server.

This behaviour prevents from reading lines from php files inside zip via `zip_entry_read()` and usage of `eval()` then.

Comment: Nothing to do with php, but all to do with how your browser interprets the code. Look at the actual source

Comment: Do a "view source" in your browser, and you'll find otherwise.... or use `<?echo htmlentities('<?this text is ignored?> this text is shown');?>`

Comment: Oh, that's true. So stupid of me, gosh

Comment: @DmitryNevzorov if my answer helped you hook me up with a check and a upvote.

Comment: you're supposed to downvote incorrect answers, not just because you feel like it.

Comment: No problem, I clearly understand what an embarassment my question is) Can't upvote your answer - no enough reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not ignoring the text inside your inner `<? .. ?>`, your browser is ignoring it.

Anything you put inside of angle braces is an HTML tag as far as your browser is concerned.

I'm not sure what you were expecting, but if you want the tags to show in the browser you have to replace the opening `<` with `&lt;`

If you actually wanted to execute the code inside the inner php tags you can just go ahead and remove the inner tags as they are redundant.